# Get response from chunked request

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, httpwebrequest, chunked

I've been struggling for a while with the getting response from WebApi endpoint, via a chunked transfer. I'm using accord library to get frames(captured voice, bytes arrays) from microphone, these arrays I'm posting to server via RestApi implemented in ASP.NET core. These data are further send via TCP client to speaker, which returns exception when streaming fails (speaker is not reachable, someone else speaking...). I need to implement push to talk like behavior, so it is necessary to use chunked transfer.

Client implentation

```
var playUri = "http://localhost:9100/speakers/play"; 
var request = WebRequest.Create(playUri);
var authorizationHeader = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string.Format("{0}:{1}", "admin", "12345"));
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", $"Basic {Convert.ToBase64String(authorizationHeader)}");
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "audio/basic";

var webRequest = request as HttpWebRequest;
webRequest.SendChunked = true;

var stream = await webRequest.GetRequestStreamAsync();
var rnd = new Random();

//Generating random byte arrays (simulating frames from microphone)
var rnd = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < 2000; i++)
{
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100));
    var b = new Byte[1000];
    rnd.NextBytes(b);

    stream.Write(b, 0, b.Length);
}

stream.Close();
stream.Dispose();
```

Server side implentation

```
[HttpPost("play")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Play( [FromHeader(Name = "Content-Type")] string contentType)
{    
    var client = new MyTcpClient(login,password);

    (bool success, string response, int? statusCode) result = (false, string.Empty, null);
    try
    {
        result = await client.PlayAudio(address, Request.Body);
    }
    catch (SocketException ex)
    {                
        result.success = false;

        if (ex.SocketErrorCode == SocketError.TimedOut)
        {
            result.statusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.GatewayTimeout;
        }
        else
        {
            result.statusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        result.success = false;
        result.statusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
    }

    if (result.success || (string.IsNullOrEmpty(result.response) && result.statusCode == null))
    {
        return Ok();
    }
    else
    {
        return StatusCode(result.statusCode.HasValue ? result.statusCode.Value : (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, result.response);
    }    
}
```

Everything works fine if speaker is reachable and no exception is thrown during streaming to speaker via TcpClient. But I don't know how to obtain response from request before writing to stream is done, to be able to inform user about problem on server side. Is there any possibility?